# Is there way to compile Qt5 programs, written with c++, to Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, cross-compilation

I'm creating a program with Qt5 and C++, and I would like to compile my program for Ubuntu Touch Preview or Ubuntu desktop arm.

I'm running those systems on Nexus 7. I have found the right C++ compiler (`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`), but how can I get Qt5 working?

Comment: If @David Planella's answer has solved your problem, you should mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The easy way

You can use an experimental feature of the Ubuntu SDK Alpha. The beauty of it is that you don't need to cross-compile.

First connect to your device:

1. Plug in your device to your computer's USB port
2. Start Qt Creator
3. Click on the devices tab
4. Click the Enable button to enable developer mode
5. Go to Tools > Ubuntu > Device > Enable > Cpp compiling on Ubuntu device (experimental)

Then start hacking:

1. Open your app's project in Qt Creator
2. Go to Build > Ubuntu > Build C++ project on Ubuntu device (experimental)

[image: Building C++ Touch projects on the device]

And off you go! :-)

## If you like a challenge

You could conceivably compile the apps on the device by hand. You might want to try the following (untested) steps:

1. [SSH into your device](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#SshAccess) running the Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview
2. Install the required development packages. Depending on what you need, you might need to add packages to the list, but here's a first shot:

   `sudo apt-get install qt5-default qtbase5-dev libqt5v8-5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev qtscript5-dev qttools5-dev qt3d5-dev qtmultimedia5-dev libqt5svg5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools qtlocation5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtpim5-dev qt-components-ubuntu`
3. Build your C++ app with your build system of choice (cmake, qmake, etc...)

Comment: Thanks a lot from your answer! I will try that with Ubuntu SDK. 
Fortunately Nexus 7 is a power full device, I tested the second way and it works also well.

Comment: Fortunately Nexus 7 is a power full device, I tested the second way  with Ubuntu desktop arm and it works well, but Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview doesn't find those dev packages.

Comment: David:I'm trying to do that but I get "Unable to locate package" for each item requested. I'm working in a Pandaboard with Ubuntu 12.40. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

There is another suggestion (third way, but hard):

1. get **linaro toolchain** for armhf

2. get **libhybris** and platform-api (from phablet-team at **launchpad.net**)

3. get dynamic libs from device (**/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf** and **/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/**)

4. patch **mkspecs** for **qmake**

5. compile

6. add **<your_app>.desktop** file to **/usr/share/applications/**

7. add lines to **/usr/share/qml-phone-shell/Applications/applications.js** (may be optional, I think)

8. push your app and resources

9. reboot shell or phone

10. Your got worked app! (I tested this!)

Answer (score 1):

Extended instruction founded on previous answer.
Keep in mind: this instruction describes Qt/Qml developing on PC for Ubuntu Touch **without ssh** connection with device and **require cross-compile tool** like linaro.

**PART 1: making environment**

1. Get **Ubuntu SDK**
2. Get toolchain: **Linaro** or wia *sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf* install toolchain and it's dependencies.
3. Get this two libs **libhybris** and **platform-api** plus Qt5 libs for armhf (can be obtained from device) or just download **tarball** with all libs (from tarball your need libs and headers, put them at */usr/arm-gnueabihf/lib* and */usr/arm-gnueabihf/include*).
4. Get modified **qmake config** - unrar it in *mkspecs* (for example, mine at */usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/*). Inside unrared directory - *qmake.conf*. If something missed on compiling - it's need to alter path variable in that file.
5. For *Qt Creator* make new compiling profile: in *Compiling and deployment* settings, on tab *Compiler* - add new compiler (*arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc*), on tab *Tools* - add new profile and specify *Device type* - General linux-device,  *Compiler* - ones, that you are added *Profile Qt* - generic (I'm using not recompiled Qt!!!), *Qt mkspec* - linux-arm-gnueabihf-gcc. It's all you need for compiling. For debugging - it's need to be specify other params. And beside it, that's better recompile Qt from sources. But I'm lazy so)

**PART 2: deploying app**

1. Wia *adb push /data/ubuntu/<some_path>* push app and resources. OS can find them at */<some_path>*. Note, there are no */data/ubuntu* part. That part is needed only by *adb*.
2. Next, need to make *<app_name>.desktop* file:

   - *adb root*
   - *adb shell*
   - *ubuntu_chroot shell* - switch to *bash* on device
   - *cd /usr/share/applications* - go in folder with *.desktop files
   - Copy any of them and edit (with *vi*) for your app purpose (name, icon, path, e.t.c.)
3. Next step, same as previous (you already in *bash* at device):
   edit file (with *vi*) */usr/share/qml-phone-shell/Applications/applications.js*, add part for your app in file, same as other apps have in that file. It must be same as in *<app_name>.desktop* file
4. Reboot shell (by killing *qml-phone-shell* process) or reboot phone (*reboot -p*)
5. Now you can launch your app from *Apps* page!

Test example and original materials:
[EN instruction](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B5kDhuHYYcvwWDZpS0puZXhnZkk/ubuntu-sdk-dev-en.html) and [RU instruction](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B5kDhuHYYcvwWDZpS0puZXhnZkk/ubuntu-sdk-dev-ru.html) with links for downloads toolchain and essential libs.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.