# Ubuntu Mobile programming language?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, language-support

I would like to develop a "where's my phone" type application for Ubuntu mobile.  I was wondering if anyone could suggest which language I should be using?  Or what would be the most appropriate?

Comment: You'd be looking at using QML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [start developing apps](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) for Ubuntu mobile devices you can use the [Qt 5](http://qt-project.org/qt5) framework.

For further information go to [Ubuntu app developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/)

---

Take a look at the following related questions:

- [How Can I get started with Ubuntu for Phone Development?](https://askubuntu.com/q/239490/62483)
- [How do I start developing applications for Ubuntu on mobile devices?](https://askubuntu.com/q/235441/62483)
- [Is there way to compile Qt5 programs, written with c++, to Ubuntu Touch?](https://askubuntu.com/q/260185/62483)

Comment: Calling it a programming language is not quite right.