# Ubuntu touch tools

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, qt-creator, cmake

I'm doing a **porting exercise** to port an application from Ubuntu to Ubuntu Touch. The application uses **gcc 4.1.2, CMake 2.6.4, binutils 2.22**.

**Q1. What tools are needed for setting up a Ubuntu Touch development environment?** I've already seen [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) link and followed every step. The link does not installs any cross compiler but I guess I'm gonna need a **cross compiler** too for compiling the applications for **arm** phones/tablets targets.

**Q2.** The QT creator in [this](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) article can be configured to use CMake but if a new project is created with QT creator to use CMake 2.8 version. **Is CMake 2.6 compatible with QT creator 2.7 based on QT 5.0.1?**

**Q3. Is there any emulator available?**

**Q4. Can a c++ code(with no gui only one daemon that runs in background) be compiled for Ubuntu Touch which works fine on Ubuntu?**

Comment: 4. Same as with my question 2 response, give it a go :P Considering that Ubuntu Touch is new to all of us.

Comment: I compiled the code in QT creator seems to compile fine but again will it work on Ubuntu Touch (arm device) as the compiler was gcc? no issues for cmake 2.6.4 also

Comment: See number 4 on my answer for how to run qt programs on a Touch device...

Answer (score 0):

[Most of this answer uses common sense sorry, a better answer is required!]

1. Nope, I think the whole point of Qt is that it is meant to be cross-platform. I imagine that they would give you the tools if you needed them. I also suspect that if you are porting, you will have to rewrite the whole program in Qt/QML.
2. Don't know sorry. Why don't you try it? :P I think you should be able to downgrade it by uninstalling then reinstalling packages with .debs.
3. Here's the instructions to install the emulator: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-run-unity-next-on-your-desktop.
4. [Is there way to compile Qt5 programs, written with c++, to Ubuntu Touch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260185/is-there-way-to-compile-qt5-programs-written-with-c-to-ubuntu-touch) This will tell you how to run Qt5 programs on an ARM device. YOU DON'T EVEN NEED TO CROSS-COMPILE!!!

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Thankx for reply. I'm new to QT. 
for 1. If the QT Quick Application (Built-in Elements) is used then the code can have a c++ part also if its so then the c++ code has to be compiled with a cross compiler. I don't know if its gonna translate the c++ code into QML.
2. I'll try.

Comment: Thankx for the link i atleast got the name of the cross compiler to use.